# A GitHub hook to perform web service call on update of issue

Tags: git, github, github-api

We have an internal bug tracking system we are trying to integrate with GitHub so our business and support users can comfortably use the system to raise cases and issues, but the development team can manage this all through GitHub.

So doing the push from our system to GitHub is fine, it is getting our system to be updated when a GitHub issue is updated or closed.

Anybody have any good ideas on how we might go about this?

Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the post receive url hook to hit a url on your system that sets off a background job to update that project via the issues api.

http://help.github.com/post-receive-hooks/